# Most efficient way to replace elements based on first 3 characters of every original element in very large dataframe for over 20,000 selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I am trying to replace entire elements in an array based upon the first 3 characters of all original elements in specific columns of a large dataframe (where applicable based on a dictionary). This process needs to be repeated many times. Given that there are over 20,000 selected columns, the for-loop below is very slow.

Please note that all the elements within are strings.

```
  d = {'0/0': 0, '0/1': 1, '1/0': 1,  '1/1': 2, "./.": 3}
  cols = list(set(merged.columns) - set(["subject", "Group"]))
  for col in cols:
       merged[col] = merged[col].str[:3].replace(d)
```

I have made an attempt to use lamda functions (please see below), however, this has been slow as well. I believe it is the apply function that slowed things down. (Note: Using Applymap was slow as well)

```
d = {'0/0': 0, '0/1': 1, '1/0': 1, '1/1': 2, "./.": 3}

cols = list(set(merged.columns) - set(["subject", "Group"]))

merged[cols] = merged[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].replace(d))
```

I am seeking for more efficient approaches such as using vectorisation, but have not been able to identify a way forward.

An example of the data can be seen below (please note that it is much smaller than the actual data and the strings within each cell are much longer)

```
data = {
    'Sample1': ['0/0:0,1:33', '0/1:2,3:32', '1/0:4,5', '1/1:6,7', './.:8,9'],
    'Sample2': ['0/0:10,11', '0/1:12,13', '1/0:14,15', '1/1:16,17', './.:18,19'],
    'Sample3': ['0/0:20,21', '0/1:22,23', '1/0:24,25:23', '1/1:26,27', './.:28,29'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Update: Data sample with a representative size

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sample = ['0/0:0,1:33', '0/1:2,3:32', '1/0:4,5', '1/1:6,7', './.:8,9', '0/0:10,11', 
          '0/1:12,13', '1/0:14,15', '1/1:16,17', './.:18,19', '0/4:20,21', 
          '0/1:22,23', '1/0:24,25:23', '1/1:26,27', './.:28,29']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(sample, (2000, 20000)))
```

Comment: A minor idea: Try `inplace=True`

Comment: maybe make some minimal reproducible example, more people will be willing to help you

Comment: For next question: it is best when example data has the same size you encounter in real world and same values distribution (if it is important). Random, obfuscated, etc. but as similar as possible

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have permission to share the original data.

Comment: But whenever I can, I will do that.

Comment: how many rows? i know your example has 20000columns

Comment: Around 800. In the future this value will increase when there are new samples. But for now, ~800.

Comment: What is your maximum rows estimate in the future?

Comment: I think around 2000 in the near future. But since this the sample size, the bigger this value, the better from a data collection perspective. (But a challenge when it comes to programming)

Comment: what is `merged`? As it is, your example is not reproducible.

Comment: The closest example would be the following:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sample = ['0/0:0,1:33', '0/1:2,3:32', '1/0:4,5', '1/1:6,7', './.:8,9', '0/0:10,11', 
          '0/1:12,13', '1/0:14,15', '1/1:16,17', './.:18,19', '0/0:20,21', 
          '0/1:22,23', '1/0:24,25:23', '1/1:26,27', './.:28,29']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(sample, (2000, 20000)))

Comment: What is the desired behavior for the cells where the first 3 chars do **not match** any element in `d`?

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

lets make 2000 X 20000 sample

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sample = ['0/0:0,1:33', '0/1:2,3:32', '1/0:4,5', '1/1:6,7', './.:8,9', '0/0:10,11', 
          '0/1:12,13', '1/0:14,15', '1/1:16,17', './.:18,19', '0/0:20,21', 
          '0/1:22,23', '1/0:24,25:23', '1/1:26,27', './.:28,29']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(sample, (2000, 20000)))
```

[image]

**Code**

make mapper

```
m = {'0/0': 0, '0/1': 1, '1/0': 1,  '1/1': 2, "./.": 3}
```

I think there is no big difference between using a for loop and using `apply`, as they are both loop.

However, `map` is a little faster than `replace` (note that the unmapped results return NaN), and it is more efficient to  `apply` with axis=1 because there are more columns than rows.

1. replace (your code)

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].replace(m))
```

result:

```
1min 9s ± 5.81 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

2. map with axis=0(default)

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].map(m))
```

result:

```
52.9 s ± 1.3 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

3. map with axis=1

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].map(m), axis=1)
```

result:

```
18.3 s ± 1.54 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It is possible to obtain slightly more efficient results

Comment: Thank you. Based on your results, I can implement the following?


merged[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].map(m), axis=1)

Comment: But `df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].map(d), axis=1)` returns `NaN` if the 3-chars are not in `m`.

Comment: @AIBball  try it.

Comment: @PierreD So, answer says 'note that the unmapped results return NaN'. And in the case of converting string data to `int`, it is usually more useful to convert the unmapped result to NaN rather than leaving it as a string.

Comment: `NaN` can't be in an `dtype=int` array, so the whole thing becomes `float64`. Better to define a default value IMHO. And, with a little bit of `numpy` and `pd.factorize()`, this gets us to 6.2 seconds for your 2Kx20K array.

Comment: @PierreD Even though the dtype is changed to float, I cannot think of any general case where it is good for the unmapped data to remain as a string, considering the reason for encoding. And I think the answerer can use it flexibly because it has already been announced in the answer that it will be returned as NaN.

Comment: I didn't say it should be a string. In my answer I just used `default=-1`.

Comment: @PierreD You can set the default value that you set in your answer. The fact that answer already used the `replace` function does not mean that setting a default value additionally is not a major consideration in general. However, the fact that map returns NaN, which is the content of your first comment, was already announced in the answer. Even if it needs to be set default value, it is not impossible to set the default value when it is needed by using the map function. I don't think there is any meaningful exchange of comments.

Answer (score 3):

How about this, using `numpy`'s `<U3` type to extract fast the first three characters? On a `2000 x 20_000` frame it takes 6.22 seconds (AWS `r6id.2xlarge`).

```py
def replace_match(df, d, n=3, default=-1):
    codes, uniques = pd.factorize(df.to_numpy().ravel().astype(f'<U{n}'))
    new = np.array([d.get(e, default) for e in uniques])
    return pd.DataFrame(
        new[codes].reshape(df.shape),
        index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Test, with some cells purposely not matching (for which the output will be `default`):

```py
sample = ['0/0:0,1:33', '0/4:2,3:32', '1/0:4,5', '1/1:6,7', './.:8,9', '0/0:10,11', 
          '0/1:12,13', '1/0:14,15', '1/1:16,17', './.:18,19', '0/0:20,21', 
          '0/1:22,23', '1/0:24,25:23', '1/1:26,27', './.:28,29']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(sample, (2000, 20_000)))

d = {'0/0': 0, '0/1': 1, '1/0': 1,  '1/1': 2, './.': 3}

%timeit replace_match(df, d)
6.22 s ± 46.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

By comparison:

PaulS's solution:

```py
default = -1

%timeit df.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x[:3], default))
14 s ± 44.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(One of) Panda Kim's solution(s):

```py
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].map(d), axis=1)
8.06 s ± 58.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

...and note that this fills NaN where there are no matches in `d`, thus making the frame `dtype=float64`.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1 (fastest)**

The fastest solution found until now (it takes only `3.27s`, dataframe of `(2000, 20000)` dimension), which is based on the idea of getting the first 3 bytes of each dataframe element (`S3` dtype) and then using nested `np.where` and comparing bytes:

```
a = df.astype('S3').to_numpy()

pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(a == b'0/1', 1, 
             np.where(a == b'0/0', 0, 
                      np.where(a == b'1/1', 2,
                               np.where(a == b'1/0', 1, 3)))))
```

Performance:

- This new solution:

  3.27 s ± 30.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

**Solution 2**

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(lambda x: d[x[:3]])(df.values))
```

Performance:

The faster known solution before this my solution was @PierreD's one. Comparing with this my solution (on my machine, dataframe of `(2000, 20000)` dimension):

- Mine:

  7.31 s ± 70.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- @PierreD's solution:

  9.55 s ± 66.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

**Solution 3**

Alternatively:

```
df.map(lambda x: d[x[:3]])
```

---

Output:

```
   Sample1  Sample2  Sample3
0        0        0        0
1        1        1        1
2        1        1        1
3        2        2        2
4        3        3        3
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the desired output. But somehow I ended up with AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'. Would you know why this is the case? I am using pandas 1.3.4 and also 1.5.3 on a different machine.

Comment: May I ask if you are working with pandas series of dataframe?

Comment: For `pandas<2.1.0`, use `.applymap()` instead of `.map`. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

Comment: Since your pandas version is lower than the `2.1.0`, as @PierreD suggests, use `applymap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 1):

** Update based on the sample example:

```
df = df.stack().str.extract(r'([^:]+)', expand=False).replace(d).unstack()

print(df)

 Index     Sample1  Sample2  Sample3
    0        0        0        0
    1        1        1        1
    2        1        1        1
    3        2        2        2
    4        3        3        3
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. I am also attempting to add an example right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add a benchmark allowing to test all functions in the same calls easily (and with the same size of dataframe):

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev


def build_dataframe(size):
    sample = [
        "0/0:0,1:33",
        "0/1:2,3:32",
        "1/0:4,5",
        "1/1:6,7",
        "./.:8,9",
        "0/0:10,11",
        "0/1:12,13",
        "1/0:14,15",
        "1/1:16,17",
        "./.:18,19",
        "0/0:20,21",
        "0/1:22,23",
        "1/0:24,25:23",
        "1/1:26,27",
        "./.:28,29",
    ]
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(sample, (size, size)))


def str_method(data):
    data = data.copy()
    d = {"0/0": 0, "0/1": 1, "1/0": 1, "1/1": 2, "./.": 3}
    for col in data.columns:
        data[col] = data[col].str[:3].replace(d)


def apply_method(data):
    data = data.copy()
    d = {"0/0": 0, "0/1": 1, "1/0": 1, "1/1": 2, "./.": 3}
    data[data.columns] = data[data.columns].apply(lambda x: x.str[:3].replace(d))


def stack_method(data):
    data = data.copy()
    d = {"0/0": 0, "0/1": 1, "1/0": 1, "1/1": 2, "./.": 3}
    data.stack().str.extract(r"([^:]+)", expand=False).replace(d).unstack()

def replace_match(data, n=3, inplace=False):
    d = {"0/0": 0, "0/1": 1, "1/0": 1, "1/1": 2, "./.": 3}
    pre = data.to_numpy().astype(f'U{n}')
    return data.where(
        np.isin(pre, np.array(list(d)), invert=True),
        pd.DataFrame(pre, index=df.index, columns=df.columns).replace(d),
        inplace=inplace,
    )


def map_method(data):
    data = data.copy()
    d = {"0/0": 0, "0/1": 1, "1/0": 1, "1/1": 2, "./.": 3}
    data.map(lambda x: d[x[:3]])


turn_number = 100
df = build_dataframe(1000)
for one_method in [str_method, apply_method, stack_method, map_method, replace_match]:
    function_to_test = partial(one_method, data=df)
    durations = timeit.Timer("function_to_test()", globals=globals()).repeat(
        repeat=turn_number, number=1
    )
    print(f"{one_method.__name__}, mean {mean(durations)*10**3} ms, deviation {stdev(durations)*10**3} ms")
```

If you have access to a multi core computer, you should take a look to [dask](https://docs.dask.org). You would be able to do something like this:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd. # don't know how you build your datatframe
...
# with one of the method.
data2 = data.map(lambda x: d[x[:3]]
data2.compute()
```

Here are my results of the different methods:

```
str_method, mean 1940.1417385198874 ms, deviation 30.65625035255771 ms
apply_method, mean 2049.7742383097648 ms, deviation 66.40606504300902 ms
stack_method, mean 1921.710312769137 ms, deviation 27.082265869582276 ms
map_method, mean 900.7486290999805 ms, deviation 13.709531124297671 ms
replace_match, mean 1385.514028930047 ms, deviation 20.934190486529495 ms
```

If you're using Pierre D solution, it will have a little more work adapting the solution to dask.